# Programmatically selecting a node from the Project properties dialog in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an Eclipse plug-in which adds 2 property pages to the project.

The second property page is a subpage to property page 1. Basically, if a person expands property page 1 node, then property page 2 is shown.

In property page 1, there is a button called "Advanced settings" which, when clicked, should open and set focus to property page 2.

How can I do the same programmatically?

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show use some things that you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no designated way to select another property page from within a property page.

Your only chance is to cast the container to `FilteredPreferenceDialog`. This class has a public method to change the currently shown page. For example:

```java
IPreferencePageContainer container = getContainer();
FilteredPreferenceDialog dialog = ( FilteredPreferenceDialog )container;
dialog.setCurrentPageId( "page-id" );
```

The downside of this workaround is that `FilteredPreferenceDialog` is an internal class.

Comment: This works the way i want, but yea its an internal class, any suggestion to do it another way ?

Comment: I am afraid, no, other than [opening an enhancement request at Platform/UI](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform) to provide API for that. Thus you would eventually get rid of the reference to internal. If you decide to do that, please post a link to the bugzilla entry here.

Answer (score 2):

Use `PreferencesUtil.createPropertyDialogOn` method like:

```
PreferencesUtil.createPropertyDialogOn(
 Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell(), proj,<page_id>, null, null).open();
```

You can check the javadoc for other overloaded methods of `createPropertyDialogOn` [here](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/dialogs/PreferencesUtil.html#createPropertyDialogOn-org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell-org.eclipse.core.runtime.IAdaptable-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.Object-).

Comment: That works for Preference pages but not for Properties.

Comment: It works for project's property dialog. I tried it on C project property dialog and able to select the node automatically.

Comment: Ok so the above snippet works, but it opens up a new shell instead of staying on the same shell